# Coldfusion 10 Webservice WSDL caching

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl, coldfusion-10

I am having problems with the modification of a webservice under ACF10.
I changed a webservice by adding some fields and functionality on our development environment. When I request the WSDL of our UNCHANGED live webservice (by navigation to `http://[path to cfc]?WSDL`) the wsdl file of the changed development webservice is shown. Users consuming the live (unchanged) webservice get a 500 error 'internal server error'.

When using ‘Clear Template Cache Now’ in CF Administrator, and requesting the live wsdl, the correct wsdl is showing and users manage to consume the live webservice. But as soon as the develop wsdl is requested, the live wsdl changes into the development one.

I already tried/checked the following:

- Application names are different
- Deleting the webservices from `<installdir>/coldfusion10/cfusion/stubs/`

PS: The development WS has been moved to a virtual directory under IIS7

Answer (score 0):

I built a small cfm template that I could use to reset the web service cache.  I'd run it when I ran into these caching problems and it cleared it up.

You'll have to swap out myURL/myWebService.cfm for your own wsdl URL.

```
<cfset wsdl = "http://myURL/MyWebService.cfm?WSDL">
<cfset createObject("java", "coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory").XmlRpcService.refreshWebService(wsdl)>
```

Note: You run this template on the ColdFusion server that consumes the web service that is causing caching problems.